# I'm facing problem with insering data with my database and I'm also not sure about the file path which I wrote

Tags: php

I'm creating a form and want to insert the user's data along with a random profile image, but my data is not inserting in phpMyAdmin.

I'm using sublime text-editor.

````
if(empty($error_array)) {
    $password = md5($password);

    $rand = rand(1, 2);

    if($rand == 1)
        $profile_pic = "E:/xampp/htdocs/social/assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/head_emerald.png";
    else if($rand == 2)
        $profile_pic = "E:/xampp/htdocs/social/assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/head_deep_blue.png";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$fname', '$em', '$password', '$date', '$profile_pic', '0', '0', 'no', ',')"); ```
}
````

My data is not being inserted into my database.

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address immediately

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database. It is a tool for DB management.

Comment: Do not use MD5 for passwords.

Comment: This question is essentially unanswerable without guessing or further details. See the linked duplicates on the most relevant things to try at least.